# For loop over enumerate() with two variables

Tags: python, range, nested-loops, enumerate

What does this code do? And I'm talking mostly about the `i` and `framenum`:

```
for i, framenum in enumerate(range(start, end + 1)):                  
    s.append(self.getSkeleton(framenum))
    d[i] = self.getDepth(framenum)
    u[i] = to_grayscale(self.getUser(framenum))
    g[i] = to_grayscale(self.getRGB(framenum))
```

Can I say that for every one change that `i` has will `framenum` change `range(start, end + 1)` times?
Is this the equivalent of:

```
for i in enumerate(range(start, end + 1)):
    for framenum in enumerate(range(start, end + 1)):              
        s.append(self.getSkeleton(framenum))
        d[i] = self.getDepth(framenum)
        u[i] = to_grayscale(self.getUser(framenum))
        g[i] = to_grayscale(self.getRGB(framenum))
```

Answer (score 4):

Nope, they are not equivalent. What happens is that, in Python, when the elements of your iterable are also iterables, you can unpack their values in your loop definition, which is what happens in the first example.

In other words, `enumerate` returns a generator of tuples. These tuples have two elements: the index and the actual value of the enumerated object.

As each tuple has two elements, doing `for i, framenum in...` is an easy and readable way to name each element of your tuples. It's basically the same as it would be to do:

```
for tup in enumerate(range(start, end + 1)):
    i = tup[0]
    framenum = tup[1]
```

In your second example, you're iterating over the same iterable twice. Both `i` and `framenum` will always be one of the tuples generated by `enumerate`, so it definitely would never make sense.

**A few more examples:**

```
iterable1 = [[1,2], [3,4]]
for i, j in iterable1:
    print(i)
    print(j)
```

`i` will be 1 and `j` will be 2 in the first iteration.

```
for i in iterable1:
    print(i)
```

`i` will be `[1,2]` in the first iteration.

```
iterable2 = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
for i, j, k in iterable2:
    print(i)
    print(j)
    print(k)
```

`i` will be 1, `j` will be 2 and `k` will be 3 in the first iteration.

```
for i in iterable2:
    print(i)
```

`i` will be `[1,2,3]` in the first iteration

```
for i,j in iterable2:
    print(i)
    print(j)
```

This will raise an error as the elements (`[1,2,3]` and `[4,5,6]`) are not iterables with exactly 2 elements.

Comment: it seems that "i" goes from 0 to ((end + 1) - start), and "framenum" goes from start to (end + 1). Not very intuitive syntax, but I understand what it does now

Comment: @Pototo Iterating over `enumerate(range(...))` is unusual since `i` can be calculated from `framenum`. It's more common to see loops over `enumerate(someList)` in order to have both the list items and their indices available at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not. `enumerate` returns the index and the value. Consequently, `enumerate(range(start, end+1))` will return `(start, start)`, `(start + 1, start + 1)`, ... `(end, end)`. In other words, `i` and `framenum` will always have the exact same value.

If you want the nested for loop behavior described, you should use the [product iterator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) from the itertools module. In other words, replace `enumerate(range(start, end+1))` with `product(range(start, end+1), range(start, end+1))`.